# Convert yuv21 to rgb and rgb back to yuv21 by opencv

Tags: android, c++, opencv

How could I convert NV21(camera format of android phones) to rgb(3 channels,24bits) and convert the rgb back to NV21? I need to convert it back to cv::Mat but not android BitMap.

My solution

```
//All of them are 24bits per pixel
cv::cvtcolor(nv_21_mat, rgb_mat, CV_YUV2RGB_NV21);
cv::cvtcolor(rgb_mat, nv_21_mat, CV_RGB2YUV);
```

Is this correct?By the way, color format of opencv looks confuse, like
CV_RGB2YUV, CV_YUV2RGB, I do not know it is convert to YUV444, YUV420 or YUV422, or how to specify which YUV format I want them to convert to. Do anyone know the details of them?Thanks

Comment: http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#NV21 Looks like NV21 is similar to I420 with small (but essential) difference U and V planes are interleaved. Looking at the CV constants - I see no proper conversion from RGB format to NV21. So if you really need this RGB2NV21 conversion - you may need to implement it yourself. For example converting to I420 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.E2.80.B2UV420p_.28and_Y.E2.80.B2V12_or_YV12.29_to_RGB888_conversion and then swapping some  4 bit patterns to achieve interleaving

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky So opencv only provide NV21 to RGB right now? Besides, do you have image encoded by NV21? I want to use it to test my conversion works or not(frame of my android phone is BGR24)

Comment: Same question on the opencv forum still has no answer http://answers.opencv.org/question/55355/rgb-to-nv21-conversion/. As for your second question - I never worked with NV21 format - so I have no samples available